# Can't select parent of selected day in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I made a calendar with the [jQuery UI plugin datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

---

What I want to do is to append an element after the `tr`, where the selected day is in. In the structure below, I marked the `tr`, which I try to select with `<---- *THIS ROW*`.

The structure of the calendar, which the plugin creates, looks somehow like this:

```
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar>
  <thead>...not important...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr> <---- *THIS ROW*
      <td class="ui-datepicker-current-day">8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...and so on
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I tried to do that with the following code:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar").find(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent("tr").addClass("open");
```

I tried several other methods like `.closest()`, but none of them worked either.
Does anyone know how I can select that?

Here you have a snippet:

```js
$('#calendar').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  onSelect: function(){
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").find(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent("tr").addClass("open");
  }
});
```

```css
tr.open{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: `parent()` jQuery method does not accept an argument because an node has only a single parent so there there is no reason to filter it. On the other hand, `parents()` does because it returns all the parents up to the html tag.

Comment: @Stphane Okay thanks, that doesn't make it work tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the datepicker is redrawn each time a date gets selected.

You can use `setTimeout()` function to schedule the class addition so that it gets executed after the DOM has changed and the picker has been redrawn:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar")
          .find(".ui-datepicker-current-day")
          .parent().addClass("open");
      }, 100);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
tr.open {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because there is not any element with the CSS class `ui-datepicker-current-day` at the moment of the event execution. You could postpone a bit the calling until the CSS class is set:

```js
$('#calendar').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  onSelect: function(){
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").find(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent("tr").addClass("open")
    }, 10);
    
  }
});
```

```css
tr.open{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar tr:eq(1)")`

Comment: Yes, that works, but that isn't what I want to do. The `tr` of the selected date is dynamic. So sometimes it's the first row, sometimes the 2nd, ....

Comment: then try again with .closest("tr") you will find it ;)

Comment: actually not, no.

Comment: $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").closest("tr") it not working?

Comment: This does not answer the actual issue. "Selecting" the `<tr>` element that is the parent of the selected date (`<td>`).